# Why is the wrapfig environment placed at bottom of Sharelatex document?

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, wrap

I'm, trying to place a figure to the right of some text, which wraps around the figure.

But when I write the following code, the figure ends up after the text (to the left?!) instead. Why isn't this working?

Thanks.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\graphicspath{ {images/}}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[left=0.9in, right=1in, bottom=1.25in, top=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{Name \\ Address \\ Phone \textbar \hspace{0cm} Mail}
\end{center}}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{0.5cm}
\centering\LARGE{\textbf{Curriculum Vitae}}  \\
\normalsize
\noindent \flushleft \subsection*{\Large{Profile}}\\ 

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{Foto.jpg}
\end{wrapfigure}

The text I wish to wrap around the figure. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: your `\LARGE{` will make the entire document large, I think you intended `{\LARGE`  with the `{` before the size change to limit its scope. (which is why you needed `\normalsize` to set the size back)

Comment: `\noindent` is just making a spurious paragraph that will look like extra vertical space before the heading.   `\flushleft` is never intended to be used as a command (that would be `\raggedright`) but as `\begin{flushleft}`

Comment: your example just makes the error: `! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{center}.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in the input, most of which generate errors or warnings in the log, once they are fixed the wrapfiggure works as expected. The main error is that you can not use wrapfigure in a list, and the misused `\flushleft` command starts a list environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\graphicspath{ {images/}}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[left=0.9in, right=1in, bottom=1.25in, top=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{Name \\ Address \\ Phone \textbar \hspace{0cm} Mail}


\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{0.5cm}
%NO! \centering\LARGE{\textbf{Curriculum Vitae}}  \\

{\centering\LARGE\textbf{Curriculum Vitae}\par}
%NO!  \\

\normalsize
%NO!\noindent 
%NO! \flushleft
 \subsection*{\Large{Profile}}
%NO!\\ 

\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{0.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure}

The text I wish to wrap around the figure. 
The text I wish to wrap around the figure. 
The text I wish to wrap around the figure. 
The text I wish to wrap around the figure. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! However, why is the figure positioned slightly below the starting line? How can I move up a bit, so that it is aligned with "Profile" or the first line?

Comment: @Lovsovs `\vspace{-10pt}\includegraphics...` (or more to suit whatever you want)